# How to debug this crash on Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I need advice debugging a crash reported on the Play Store for my app. I pasted the crash at the bottom of this message. The challenge is no message is reported on the Store for crashes anymore, and the crash is entirely within Google's code. I also have many RecyclerViews in my app, and I have literally no idea which one is causing the issue. It only seems to happen once per month for ~200 users, so I doubt it's a simple error like forgetting to `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Any tips or tricks I can use here? Thanks in advance.

Here is the crash:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6023)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5958)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5954)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:2226)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy (LinearLayoutManager.java:1331)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy (LinearLayoutManager.java:1075)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollStep (RecyclerView.java:1829)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run (RecyclerView.java:5155)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:635)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is about **IndexOutOfBoundsException** which means adapter mention here don.t receive ArrayList properly and it's throwing an error. Check adapter arraylist and fix it. Next time use Crashlytics rather than Play store to observe crash

Comment: Yeah I know the general cause but I have five different adapters.